# how to read write ini files in html

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I am trying to create a program using HTML, which will be compiled for android. How can I create save game data for the app? I need to save thing such as health, money, etc. Would there be a way to do this with an INI file? I will be converting the entire html folder, including .js and .css into one apk, as well as a windows .exe. Is there a way for either or both of these systems to parse an ini file. Note: I am having some trouble with javascript, so a function that could be called like the following would be great:
`saveINI(filename, section, key, value)`
jQuery is fine too, as long as the function is simple to call. 
Note: It doesnt matter where the ini file is saveable as long as the user would be okay with it

Update:  I need a way that the user won't accidentally delete the save data accidentally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INI really isn't your best choice here. There are a few problems with it, one of the more obvious ones is that they're easily editable and can be rife for cheating.

You're best off investigating an SQL database, something like SQLite - which will easily store key/value pairs like `money = 550`. There are implementations everywhere which should help, and it works on Windows and Android (amongst others).

You (probably) however can't work with it directly from HTML/JS.

Here's a good tutorial on Android SQLite:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If you're using PhoneGap, you could try this:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/731

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to access this data from another application, you can use [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). This is a native feature of javascript so you don't need external libraries. You just reference the `localStorage` object (persists data between sessions) or the `sessionStorage` (persists data just for a session) and store/retrieve items from it like:

```
Storage.getItem(key);
Storage.setItem(key, value);
```